# Using a PHP foreach loop within another foreach loop

Tags: php, sql-server, foreach

I am trying to populate a table with rows from a database. However, one of the columns is a dropdown that needs to be populated with more than one value, therefore needing to use fetchAll. However, I am having trouble since I am using a foreach construct inside another foreach construct.

I'm guessing this isn't possible, or am I just doing something wrong? How can I find a workaround so that I can populate the entire table while also populating the dropdown with more than just one value, but still having it default to the value that it is in the database?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT TOP 100 *
        FROM Table_OS_List
        ORDER BY [CURRENT_SKU] ASC";


$drops = "SELECT [Purchasing_Group]
        FROM Table_OS_List
        GROUP BY [Purchasing_Group]";
$drop = $dbh->query($drops);
?>

<?php
    /* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows) {
    ?>
    <tr class="row">    
        <td class="old_sku" id="old_sku"><?php echo intval ($rows['OLD_SKU'])?></td>
        <td class="current_sku" id="current_sku"><?php echo intval ($rows['CURRENT_SKU'])?></td>
        <td class="id" id="id" style="display: none;"><?php echo intval ($rows['ID'])?></td>


        <td class="dropdown-select" id="purchgroup">
            <select id="selected_group" class="selected_group" disabled>
                <?php foreach($drop->fetchAll() as $dropdown) { ?>

                  <option class="choice" value="Purchasing Group"><?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?></option>

                <?php } ?>

            </select>
        </td>


        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['ID'])?>" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

**NOTE**
This code correctly populates the entire table, however the dropdown list only has the value that is in each row and is not populated with the other value options if I need to select something different:

```
<?php
    /* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows) {
    ?>
    <tr class="row">    
        <td class="old_sku" id="old_sku"><?php echo intval ($rows['OLD_SKU'])?></td>
        <td class="current_sku" id="current_sku"><?php echo intval ($rows['CURRENT_SKU'])?></td>
        <td class="id" id="id" style="display: none;"><?php echo intval ($rows['ID'])?></td>


        <td class="dropdown-select" id="purchgroup">
            <select id="selected_group" class="selected_group" disabled>

                <option class="choice" value="Purchasing Group"><?php echo $rows['Purchasing_Group'];?></option>

            </select>
        </td>           

        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['ID'])?>" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

**EDIT:**

Each dropdown is automatically defaulting to Bowling Green even if that row should not be Bowling Green. Most rows are either Southeast or Michigan but regardless of what it should be, it is defaulting to Bowling Green for some reason

[image]

[image]

Comment: My first guess, you are just doing it wrong, lets have a closer look

Comment: This needs to be changed as well  `<option class="choice" value="<?php echo $rows['Purchasing_Group'];?>"><?php echo $rows['Purchasing_Group'];?></option>`

Comment: Create a new query for the drop downs instead of using the first row result from the initial query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, doing it wrong, you are consuming the second resultset on completion of the first iteration of the outer foreach so instead retrieve the dropdown contents into an array so you can reuse it many times

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT TOP 100 *
        FROM Table_OS_List
        ORDER BY [CURRENT_SKU] ASC";


$drops = "SELECT [Purchasing_Group]
        FROM Table_OS_List
        GROUP BY [Purchasing_Group]";
$drop = $dbh->query($drops);
$allDrops = $drop->fetchAll();

?>

<?php
    /* Foreach loop that brings in information to populate table */
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows) {
    ?>
    <tr class="row">    
        <td class="old_sku" id="old_sku"><?php echo intval ($rows['OLD_SKU'])?></td>
        <td class="current_sku" id="current_sku"><?php echo intval ($rows['CURRENT_SKU'])?></td>
        <td class="id" id="id" style="display: none;"><?php echo intval ($rows['ID'])?></td>


        <td class="dropdown-select" id="purchgroup">
            <select id="selected_group" class="selected_group" disabled>
                <?php 
                foreach($allDrops as $dropdown) { 
        //--------------^^^^^^^^^
        // Also changed the way you fill the option tag below
                ?>

                  <option class="choice" 
                          value="<?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>">
                    <?php echo $dropdown['Purchasing_Group'];?>
                  </option>

                <?php } ?>

            </select>
        </td>


        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="delete" name="delete" id="<?php echo intval ($rows['ID'])?>" value="Delete"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the real issue is that `value="Purchasing Group"` is hard-coded so regardless of the option selected, only one choice is actually available.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ooo let me check that

Comment: Yeah, OP's question is quite scatter-brained and a bit incoherent so it's an easy detail to miss.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Except once you have done a FetchAll the resultset is fully consumed, OP would have to re-issue the query to re-populate the resultset

Comment: Hmm this doesnt seem to be working for me...when the page is loaded, the table doesnt even load anymore

Comment: Hmm, I think you are correct but I can't test it at this moment so I've redacted that portion of my comment. I guess I just didn't know that detail because I would never choose to apply `fetchAll()` unnecessarily like that

Comment: Are you sure you got all the changes?

Comment: Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. Does that identify any errors?

Comment: In my PHP error log, this is what i get `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: There are no more rows in the active result set.  Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved.'`

Comment: Which line would that be refering to please?

Comment: And are you sure that was not from the code before you changed it, it sounds like the sort of error you should have been getting before my amendments

Comment: I had another foreach elsewhere in my code that was using the previous fetchAll before you changed it. I went ahead and fixed that and now it works so everything is good from your end. Thank you!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well, it looks like I was completely oblivious to this somehow, but it looks like the values are brought in to the dropdowns correctly, however, it is not differentiating which value should be in each row. It all defaults to the same value in each dropdown in each row. Do you know a way to get around this? So for example, it's bringing in values 1, 2, and 3 to each dropdown but every single dropdown has the same value 1 assigned to each row.

Comment: Ummm not sure I understand. Try adding an example to your question

Comment: Just made an edit on my post describing what was happening

Comment: You have removed the inner foreach loop rather than amend it like I suggested. Please read all the answer and the re-coded script